# Let $z_{n} = (a^n + b^n)^{1/n}$ where $0<a<b$, then show $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n=b$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $z_{n} = (a^n + b^n)^{1/n}$ where $0<a<b$, then show $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n=b$

$z_{n} = (a^n + b^n)^{1/n} = b\cdot((a/b)^n + 1)^{1/n}$

Can I use the following argument to proceed?[I have doubt because the power 1/n is not a constant]

$\lim_{n \to \infty}(a/b)^n = 0 \because 0<a/b<1$

$ \therefore \lim_{n \to \infty}((a/b)^n + 1)^{1/n} =\lim_{n \to \infty}(1)^{1/n}= 1$

$\therefore 
\lim_{n \to \infty} b\cdot((a/b)^n + 1)^{1/n} = b\cdot1 = b$

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} z_n = b$

Comment: there are many ways to do that. In addition to Siminore's approach, you can also do sandwich. It is known that (i) $2^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$ and (ii) forall n, $1 < [(a/b)^n+1]^{1/n} < 2^{1/n}$. So by sandwich...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(b^n)^{\frac {1}{n}}<(a^n+b^n)^{\frac {1}{n}}<(b^n+b^n)^{\frac {1}{n}}$$ Now take the limit to obtain $$b \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}(a^n+b^n)^{\frac {1}{n}}\leq \lim_{n \to \infty}({2b^n})^{\frac {1}{n}}=b$$ and the claim follows.

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is to deal with
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left( 1+ s^n \right)^{1/n}
$$
with $0<s<1$. You could take logarithms and compute easily
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\log (1+s^n)}{n}=0
$$
by means of some fundamental limit. Then your limit is trivially one.

Your attempt is troublesome because of the indeterminate form $[1^\infty]$ that you cannot put equal to one without further efforts.

Comment: There is no indeterminate form, it's $1^0=1.$